# Why does rescanning the blockchain fail with "Abort trap: 6"?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

After importing a wallet in simplewallet, issuing the `rescan_bc` command consistently results in the following "Abort trap: 6" error on my computer:

```
[wallet 4*****]: rescan_bc
Starting refresh...
Abort trap: 6/ 1124452
```

The `refresh` command also fails:

```
[wallet 4*****]: refresh
Starting refresh...
Abort trap: 6/ 1124458
```

It happens around height 85000. What could be the reason for this, and how should one resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to the newest [0.10.0 "Wolfram Warptangent"](https://getmonero.org/2016/09/19/monero-0.10.0-released.html) release solves for me the issue on OS X.

Answer (score 3):

Run those commands, and put the result of "bt" on a new issue on https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero:

```
ulimit -c unlimited  
gdb /path/to/bitmonerod core  # the core file migh thave a PID suffix, use it if so
bt
```

This is unexpected, and will need fixing. Please include what OS/architecture you're on, and which version of bitmonerod you are using.

Comment: I had to install gdb first on my Mac, did so with brew. Running `gdb /opt/monero/bitmonerod core` prints a bunch of warnings about `Could not open OSO archive file "/usr/local/lib/libboost_*.a"` and then nothing. After simplewallet crashed with `Abort trap: 6`, I typed `bt` in gdb, which says `No stack`. I noticed this topic was discussed previously on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4znuy9/ongoing_simplewallet_issues_macos_0940_abort_trap/).

Comment: Ah, if on a mac, try running with --max-concurrency 1

Comment: That didn't work for me. But rebuilding from the latest souce solved the problem (I used `brew install bitmonero --HEAD -v` for this). On [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/50d54y/update_on_the_official_gui/d73w3j5) the issue was referenced as [issue #942](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/942). I am seeing my transactions now being found when scanning through the blockchain. The process seems to be much faster also in the latest code.